# Objective C Integer is 0 first time, but it changes second time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsurlconnection

Okay so i have this program that is suposed to communicate over a Webserver(PHP Script)

I have this method that i want to get a random id for a table. The return data of this NSURLconnection is supose to be the amount of rows in the table.

First time i call it, its like randomid variables does not get set, but second time i run it, it does get set.

variable setting:

```
@implementation ViewController {
NSMutableData *randomData;
int randomid;
}
```

Here is my IBaction for a button:

```
- (IBAction)initVits:(id)sender {
[self randomID];
NSLog(@"Random ID: %d", randomid);    
}
```

The output first time is: Random ID: 0, second time: Random ID: a valid id

RandomID:

```
- (void) randomID {

NSString *url = @"http://ivitserdk.porkhost.dk/ivitserdk.php?function=randomid";
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]   cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:1.0];
connectionRandomID = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

randomData = [NSMutableData data];
[connectionRandomID start];
}
```

Connection did finish loading:

```
 if(connection == connectionRandomID) {
    NSString *String = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:randomData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Return: %@", String);
    int temp = [String integerValue];
    NSLog(@"temp: %d", temp);
    randomid = (arc4random() % temp) + 1;
    NSLog(@"Random: %d", randomid);
    randomData = nil;
    connectionRandomID = nil;
 }
```

Output is for all times: Return: (number of rows in table)
temp: (number of rows in table to a int)
Random: (a random number)

Its like the randomid variable does not get set the first time.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You could have come up with a more efficient random number generator algorithm...

Comment: You also could name your methods a little bit more informatively.  E.G. instead of "`randomID`" (which is also the name of an ivar within the class... eek!), how about "`createRandomIDUsingConvolutedServerInteraction`"?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann that's not long enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using asynchronous networking, so your `NSLog` is called before the random ID is retrieved from the server. There are multiple solutions to this.

- Use synchronous networking (I don't recommend this, so I don't go further into that)
- Put the `NSLog` statement or whatever you want to do when the ID is generated at the end of your `connectionDidFinishLoading` method
- If possible, I'd recommend generating the ID on the device (but I guess you need an unique key for a database, an URL or something, so this will probably not work for you)

Comment: I have multiple connection so i have like if else(connection == connectionRandom) how would i do it then?

Comment: Put whatever you want to do into the `if` block that belongs to the correct connection.

Comment: Please check my code, haven't i already done that? Also could you give an example.

Comment: Yes, you already log the generated id in the line `NSLog(@"Random: %d", randomid);` in your `connectionDidFinishLoading` method - that's the only place where you can be sure that you just retrieved data from your server. You should probably put whatever you wanted to do in the `initVits:` method here instead.

Comment: Tried that, but now it gives some error when trying to appendData: method?!

Comment: You must have changed more - you should only append data when you receive some. And if you only changed things in your `connectionDidFinishLoading` method, you couldn't have broke that.
Please provide some more information, e.g. where your `appendData:` method is called.

Comment: appendData is called in didReceiveData under if(connection == theconnectionhere)

Comment: Please provide the whole block of code (edit it into your question). Also provide the exact error you get.

Comment: I fixed it, something with ARC enabled. Thanks alot for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

[self randomID] 
returns immediatly because you are doing an async call inside randomID function.

randomid is set on the didFinish callback that it is executed after you NSLog the ivar randomid.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this ?

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
// Append the new data to receivedData.
// receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
[randomData appendData:data];
}
```

Comment: Yea i did add that, as i said it dinten't work first time i press the button, but it did 2nd time :)